# A zero sum matrix game is given: $A=\begin{bmatrix}13&29&8\\18&22&31\\23&22&19\\ \end{bmatrix}$ Reduce that game to a 2 x 2 game using dominance.

Tags: matrices, game-theory

I know that a 2 x 2 matrix is as follows:

$A=\begin{bmatrix}18&31\\23&19\\ \end{bmatrix}$

But it is not possible to reduce the original matrix by row or by columns, how is this result achieved?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Let the row player be the maximiser, and let the column player be the minimiser. Then identify which columns strongly dominate / weakly dominate another column, then apply iterative dominance. If your 2 x 2 matrix is in Nash equilibrium, you are done ([Medium](https://diptangshusen.medium.com/iterative-dominance-in-games-2fea51f7a3ff)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Suppose that in a mixed strategy of the column player he chooses Col 1 with a probability of $p$ and Col 3 with a probability of $1-p$. You can find that there exists a $p$ such that this mixed strategy dominates the pure strategy of Col 2.